# How to make a division of an amount and order by month? Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to make a division of one amount and group it by month, in which every month have the same amount and the rest should be in the last month.

Here is the data I have:
Sum: 27000, first month: M02, amount for each month: 6000

and here is the result I want:

```
Month | Amount
M02 6000
M03 6000
M04 6000
M05 6000
M06 3000
```

Comment: it is always just 5 months?

Comment: @Luuk Not always, the number of months depends on the division of the sum by each month's amount..

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63753127/edit) your query and explain how the number of months depends on the division.

Comment: @Luuk I have 3 variables, the sum, amount and first month. The number of months equals to the division of the sum by the amount, in this the example I have 27000/6000 = 4*6000 + 3000 so the number of months here is 4+1=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive SQL: the initial values can be changed bases on the currently unknown needs to have different values for them :

```
DECLARE @initialAmount float = 27000;
DECLARE @amountPerMonth float = 6000;
DECLARE @nrOfMonths int = 5;

WITH abc(amount,permonth,rest) as (
   SELECT 
      @initialAmount as amount, 
      0 as permonth, 
      @initialAmount as rest
   UNION all
   SELECT 
     CASE WHEN rest>@amountPerMonth and (permonth+1) <> @nrOfMonths THEN @amountPerMonth ELSE rest END, 
     permonth+1, 
     CASE WHEN rest>@amountPerMonth and (permonth+1) <> @nrOfMonths THEN rest - @amountPerMonth ELSE 0 END 
   FROM abc 
   WHERE permonth < @nrOfMonths
   )

SELECT * FROM abc;
```

output:

```
amount                 permonth    rest
---------------------- ----------- ----------------------
27000                  0           27000
6000                   1           21000
6000                   2           15000
6000                   3           9000
6000                   4           3000
3000                   5           0
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer solves my problem. Have a nice day